# Remote connection to the MySQL via PHP

Tags: php, mysql, ubuntu

I have Ubuntu 21.04 with the following setup:
MySQL 8.0.25
Apache2: 2.4.46
PHP: 7.4

My PHP scripts are working fine when I try to connect to the MySQL server as a 'localhost' (i.e. everything on the same servers).

Now, with a slight change in the setup, I am running my PHP scripts (and apache) on server **A**, with the MySQL server running on **B**. Both the systems are Ubuntu 21.04, running on the same intranet network (172.16.10.XX series). From the command-line of **B**, I can run the following command successfully:

```
mysql --verbose --ssl-mode=DISABLE -u user -h 172.16.10.5 -p
```

However, the connection through PHP fails and interestingly, there is no error. More precisely, the command `mysqli_connect` returns a non-NULL object whereas `mysqli_query` fails. Here is the PHP code:

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);

$con=mysqli_connect( "172.16.10.4","user","XXXXXX","myDB" );
var_dump($con);

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM tblFirst;");
?>
```

Here is the output:

```
object(mysqli)#1 (19) { 
    ["affected_rows"]=> int(0) 
    ["client_info"]=> string(79) "mysqlnd 5.0.12-dev - 20150407 - $Id: 3591daad22de08524295e1bd073aceeff11e6579 $" 
    ["client_version"]=> int(50012) 
    ["connect_errno"]=> int(0) 
    ["connect_error"]=> NULL 
    ["errno"]=> int(0) 
    ["error"]=> string(0) "" 
    ["error_list"]=> array(0) { } 
    ["field_count"]=> int(0) 
    ["host_info"]=> string(23) "172.16.10.4 via TCP/IP" 
    ["info"]=> NULL 
    ["insert_id"]=> int(0) 
    ["server_info"]=> string(23) "8.0.25-0ubuntu0.21.04.1" 
    ["server_version"]=> int(80025) 
    ["stat"]=> string(135) "Uptime: 13713 Threads: 2 Questions: 29 Slow queries: 0 Opens: 241 Flush tables: 3 Open tables: 160 Queries per second avg: 0.002" 
    ["sqlstate"]=> string(5) "00000" 
    ["protocol_version"]=> int(10) 
    ["thread_id"]=> int(16) 
    ["warning_count"]=> int(0) 
} 
query failed...
```

I also had a look at the other question with the same subject ([MySQL Database accepting remote connections, but not from PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29125406/)), but does not give many pointers.

I also experimented with the following commands (and playing with some other options!):

```
$connection = mysqli_init();
$connection->options(MYSQLI_OPT_SSL_VERIFY_SERVER_CERT,false);
$connection->ssl_set( "/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key", "/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem", NULL, NULL, NULL );
$connection->real_connect("172.16.10.4 ,"user","XXXXX","myDB", NULL, NULL,NULL, MYSQLI_CLIENT_SSL );
```

In the file `/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf`, the following lines are commented:

```
# bind-address          = 127.0.0.1
# mysqlx-bind-address   = 127.0.0.1
```

Any pointers?

Comment: `mysqli_error()` needs the connection as a parameter, try adding that and see if it gives more information.

Comment: Remove all the `if` statements and turn on error reporting

Comment: @Dharman I have edited the code as you suggested. The error is still the same. `$con` is nonNULL, but `$result` fails.

Comment: I still don't see `mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);` in your code.